# Uncaught TypeError: kendo.data.TreeListDataSource is not a function

Tags: kendo-ui, dojo, kendo-grid, kendo-treelist

I am using Kendo treeList component. I am making use of this [example](http://dojo.telerik.com/ApOCA). 
When I run the fiddle everything works fine. But when I try to run the same example locally, I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: kendo.data.TreeListDataSource is not a function` error.

I also do not see any file with the name `kendo.data.TreeListDataSource.js` or `kendo.data.TreeList*`.

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.TreeListDataSource({
      data: [ { name: "Jane Doe" }, { name: "John Doe" }]
    });
    $("#treeList").kendoTreeList({
      columns: [
          { field: "name" },
          { command: [{ name: "edit" }] }
      ],
      editable: true,
      dataSource: dataSource
    });
```

**Can this be due to the fact I am using trial version and not professional version of kendo framework?**

Comment: Are you including `kendo.all.js` ?

Comment: Yes, I have included kendo.all.js.

Comment: Your code is legit.  You said `kendo.all.js` is already referenced in your code but go in the browser console and make sure it's loaded correctly.  Also, make sure the libraries you are using are up to date since the TreeList has been introduced a few months ago.

Answer (score 0):

Its very important to maintain scripts references(jquery,kendo.all.js) as per hierarchy once check this artical  [Add CSS and JavaScript References](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/getting-started#add-css-and-javascript-references)

Answer (score 0):

Its because of old version of (kendo.all.js)script file. Use latest version of this reference script.

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to raise your content quality up